# Warning: 'Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq' in Perl

Tags: perl

I am getting a warning as:

> Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at script.pl line 53`; line 53 is`if statement`

My code snippet:

```
foreach(@array)
{
    push @gene2refseq, $_;
}

foreach(@::ids)
{
    if($_ == $gene2refseq[1])
    {
        push @::prot_gi, $gene2refseq[6];
    }
}
```

Now if I declare `$gene2refseq[1]` before `foreach(@::ids)` the same error persists; but if I initialize it before `foreach(@::ids)` viz. `$gene2refseq[1] = 0` it didn't give the error but also no results; as the value is initialized to `0`.

I think I am initializing it at a wrong place, but then where have I to initialize it? As I can't initialize it before or in `foreach(@array)`

---

*Disclaimer: I am not very good with `use warnings` and `use strict`*

---

### Edit: Solved

Thanks for the help; I just declared the `@gene2refseq` and initialized `$gene2refseq[1] = 0` before the `foreach(@array)`, and it worked fine.

Also thanks for correcting me on `foreach` usage.

### A question:

What if I have to access multiple indexes of an array? Do I have to initialize them all? As here I need to access only a single index, so I initialized it.

Comment: Why can't you initialize it before foreach(@array) ? And do yourself a favor and `use strict; use warnings;` just silly not to.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @salparadise; Yes it worked by initializing it before @array, but for that I have to first declare the `@gene2refseq`, which I did and it worked fine.
_Also, I said I am not good at use strict and use warnings; but at no place I mentioned that I am not using them._

Comment: As mentioned in the answer. @array is probably empty, or it might just have one value and only populating `$gene2refseq[0]`

Comment: @salparadise no `@array` has more than 1 element and I have checked that; the problem was with initializing the variable; which I did my initializing it before `@array`
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *“Disclaimer: I am not very good with use warnings and use strict”*? They're not hard to use! Are you saying that you often forget them? Or perhaps that you don't understand the resulting messages?

Comment: @Borodin I am just getting into the music, I earlier wrote scripts without them, but now when I have to deal with big files they got important

Comment: @Rajinder: You were wrong: they have always been important

Comment: Your use of `@::ids` is a bit of a red flag. That's going to be a package variables. And package variables are almost always the wrong approach. You should consider changing that to a lexical variable.

Comment: @Borodin Yeah surely from now on I will always make use of them.

Comment: @DaveCross can you please suggest some good reading?

Comment: @Rajinder: Start at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/) (in particular their [suggested books](http://learn.perl.org/books/)).

Comment: There's also the [Perl tutorial hub](http://perl-tutorial.org/).

Answer (score 3):

If `@gene2refeq` is empty and `@array` is empty before the start of that code snippet, then `@gene2refeq` will be empty by line 53.

To find out, print the contents of `@array` and `@gene2refeq`.  It's also possible `@::ids` contains uninitialized values, check that too.  Add a separator so you can see what's in them.

```
print "\@array is ".join(", ", @array)."\n";
print "\@gene2refeq is ".join(", ", @gene2refeq)."\n";
print "\@::ids is ".join(", ", @::ids)."\n";
```

As to your question about when to initialize things, there's a difference between *declaring* a variable and *initializing* it.  `my` and `our` declare a variable to exist lexically and globally respectively.  Then you can populate (initialize) it.

The basic pattern of your program might look something like this.

```
my @ids;
...code to populate @ids...

my @gene2refeq;
...code to populate @gene2refeq...

my @array;
...code to populate @array...

push @gene2refeq, @array;

die "\@gene2refeq is not long enough, ".join(", ", @gene2refeq)
    unless @gene2refeq >= 7;

my @prot_gi;
foreach my $id (@ids) {
    if($id == $gene2refseq[1])
    {
        push @prot_gi, $gene2refseq[6];
    }
}
```

A few other points.  That first `foreach` loop is better written as simply...

```
push @gene2refseq, @array;
```

Using `@::ids` and `@::prot_gi` is odd.  That's shorthand for getting the global variable `@ids` in the `main` package.  It shouldn't be necessary and smells like cargo culting.

Comment: No the `@array` is not empty; I have checked that
Also this loop structure is in between a `while loop` for a file with more than 10M lines (tab separated), so I want to keep only a single line of the file for processing at any moment.
Also you mentioned that `"Using @::ids and @::prot_gi is odd"` what other way is to use them, as they are global variables.

Comment: @Rajinder Check `@::ids` as well, it could contain uninitialized values.  It should not be necessary to qualify `@ids` and `@prot_gi`, I suspect you're working around `strict` poorly.  Declare them with `our @ids` and `our @prot_gi` or better yet, make them lexical (ie. only existing within the declared scope) with `my @ids` and `my @prot_gi` if there's no pressing need for them to be global.

Comment: yes these are global and in the other part of my code I have defined them as `our` but here is given just the snippet of my code